# Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code. Find the largest `palindrome` made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

```
function largestPalindrome(){

    for(var i =999; i>100; i--){
        for(var j = 999; j>100; j--){
            var mul = j*i;
            if(isPalin(mul)){
                return i * j;
            }
        }
    }
}

function isPalin(i){
    return i.toString() == i.toString().split("").reverse().join("");
}

console.log(largestPalindrome());
```

[This answer was close to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842861/largest-palindrome-product-in-javascript)
but still i feel the way i am doing the loop it should return me the largest product.

Comment: @VisioN: When i submit that answer, it shows wrong here. http://projecteuler.net/problem=4

Comment: Follow the algorithm: your code checks for every `i` the product with every `j`; when palindrome found it stops the search, returning the result, not keeping in mind that for next `i` and higher `j` there a highest palindrome exists. For example, your code stops searching when reaching `i = 995` and `j = 583`, while the highest palindrome has different coefficients: `i = 913` and `j = 993`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yours doesn't work properly since it checks `999*999`, then `999*998`, then `999*997` until it reaches about `999*583`. While it doesn't check `997*995` or something closer to the top
which generates a larger number

```
function largestPalindrome(){

    var arr = [];    
    for(var i =999; i>100; i--){
        for(var j = 999; j>100; j--){
            var mul = j*i;
            if(isPalin(mul)){
                arr.push(j * i);
            }
        }
    }

    return Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
}

function isPalin(i){
    return i.toString() == i.toString().split("").reverse().join("");
}

console.log(largestPalindrome());
```

**Here is another approach**, store all `palindrome` generated by 3 numbers in an array, then use `Math.max on the array` to get the largest `palindrome`

Comment: store all `palindrome` in array will unnecessarily consume memory, also no need to use the same multiplication twice (multiplication is comutative i.e. i * j === j * i)

Comment: cheeky? but i'll limit my loop to 900 since the largest is guarantee to be between 9XX * 9XX

Comment: @core_pro how did you come up with this conclusion?

Comment: Here's an improvement based on @Azder's comment, also updated for ES6 using the [`spread` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) instead of `apply`: http://codepen.io/jsejcksn/pen/MymdVN?editors=0010. Related to performance: using the `time` command in unix with Node.js reported it to run 1.36x faster and the palindrome array length was only 1239 instead of 2470.

Comment: Using the array to keep track of palindromes is not needed. Just check if new palindrome is greater than previous, and just update. Also, check for palindrome only if the multiplied value is greater than previous palindrome. 
`if(mul > maxPalindrome && isPalin(mul)) maxPalindrome = mul`

Comment: I think you wanted you inner loop to be `for(var j = i; j > 100; j--)` -- this will allow to skip half of computation.

Comment: `Math.max(...arr)` would work fine to return the max value in the array of palindromic numbers as well.

Answer (score 21):

I think if you apply maths to the problem you can decrease the guesswork really significantly.

I will write the three digit numbers as `1000 - a` and `1000 - b` which means the palindrome is `1 000 000 - 1000(a+b) + ab`.

First, let's find solutions where `ab < 1000`. Then the three leftmost digits are `1000 - (a+b)` and the three rightmost digits are `ab`.

Then I will say this is a palindrome with digits `x,y,z`:

```
100x+10y+z=ab
100z+10y+x=1000-a-b
```

thus

```
99x-99z = ab+a+b-1000
x-z = 1/99(ab+a+b-10)-10
```

So then (ab+a+b-10) is divisible by 99 and we also know that x and z being digits the left side is between -9 and 0 (the whole shebang is symmetrical so we can presume x <= z) so then `1/99(ab+a+b-10)` is between 1 and 9. We can rewrite `ab+a+b-10` as `ab+a+b+1-11=99p` so `(a+1)(b+1)=99p+11=11*(9p+1)` where p runs between 1 and 9. That's really easy:

```
for ($p = 1; $p <= 9; $p++) {
  $n = 9 * $p + 1;
  // This could be vastly optimized further.
  for ($j = 1; $j <= $n; $j++) {
    if ($n % $j === 0) {
      $a = 1001 - $n / $j;
      $b = 1001 - 11 * $j;
      $test = $a * $b;
      if (strrev($test) === (string) $test) {
        print "$a $b " . $a * $b . "\n";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now this prints only one solution which is the correct one.

Now we know 906609 is a solution so then is there a solution where ab > 1000 and 1000(a+b) - ab < 93391 ? There is not :)

Comment: Nice mathematical representation.

Comment: +1 Excellent analysis but you can not presume `x<=z` (the whole shebang is symmetrical). The number 906609 is a solution, but 609906 is not.

Answer (score 9):

As explained in @VisioN's comment:

`995*583 = 580085` is a palindrome.

`993*913 = 906609` is also a (larger) palindrome.

Your code checks `995*583` before `993*913` and exits at the first palindrome found, so it doesn't return the largest palindrome.

Solution: get the largest palindromes starting from `999*999 = 998001` downwards and check if they can be written as `xyz*abc`.

Or simply use the accepted solution from the question you linked :). Your solution, but instead of returning when you find the first palindrome, check if it is larger than the largest one already found, in which case you need to replace it. You can stop as soon as the largest palindrome is larger than `i*999`.

Answer (score 6):

A bit more optimized version with comments included. Notice, there is no need of fast return, just store the `max` and optimize the cycles to not recalculate `j*i` if `i*j` has already been checked.

```
function largestPalindrome() {

    var max = 0;

    // not using i >= 100 since 100*100 is not palindrome! :)
    for (var i = 999; i > 100; i--) {
        // because i * j === j * i, no need of both i and j
        // to count down from 999
        for (var j = i; j > 100; j--) {
            var mul = j * i;
            if (isPalin(mul) && mul > max) {
                max = i * j;
            }
        }
    }

    return max;

}

function isPalin(i) {

    // adding empty string to i instead using of .toString
    // avoids unnecessary wrapping in String object on the left side
    i = '' + i;

    // don't rely on ==,  use === instead
    return i === i.split("").reverse().join("");

}

console.log(largestPalindrome());
```

Comment: Can optimize further if you check for palindrome after checking `mul > max`. Shows considerable improvement for four 9's.
`if(mul > max && isPalin(mul))`

Comment: You can also get rid of ~1/10 of the loops by doing a check to see if i is a multiple of 10 and skipping if it is (since the resulting product would end in a zero and couldn't possibly be a palindrome).

Answer (score 4):

Suggesting a solution using underscore.js. First, find all palindromes and then loop through them starting from the largest one and return the one which has two 3-digit prime factors.

```
function isPalindrome(num) {
    var str = num.toString();
    return str.split('').reverse().join('') === str;
}

function palindromes() {
    var max = 999 * 999;
    var min = 100 * 100;
    return _.select(_.range(max, min, -1), isPalindrome);
}

palindromes().find(function (x) {
    if (_.find(_.range(999, 100, -1), function (y) {
        return (x % y === 0 && y != x / y && x / y < 1000) ? true : false;
    })) return true;
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
int largestPalindrome()
{
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 999; i > 100; --i)
    {
        int jLimit = MAX(ret / i, 100);
        for (int j = i; j > jLimit; --j)
        {
            int ans = i * j;
            if (isPalin(ans))
            {
                ret = MAX(ans, ret);
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Reasons explained above.

We can recompute the range of j when we find a palindrome product.This should be faster.

Comment: how do you limit range of j? what is the logic behind ret/i?

Answer (score 3):

The above solution will work perfectly fine but we will have issue **ONLY** when we try to find-out what are those 2 numbers (i = 913 and j = 993)

I will just modify the solution proposed by Azder

```
int max = 0;
int no1 = 0;
int no2 = 0;

// not using i >= 100 since 100*100 is not palindrome! :)
for (var i = 999; i > 100; i--) {
    // because i * j === j * i, no need of both i and j
    // to count down from 999
    for (var j = i; j > 100; j--) {
        var mul = j * i;
        if (isPalin(mul)) {
            if ((i+j) > max) {
               max = i+j;
               no1 = i; no2 = j;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Now we can get the 2 numbers (no1=993 and no2=913)

return (no1*no2);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it. I used the old fashioned way to check for a palindrome. It appears to run faster on my computer but I may be wrong. Pushing to an array, as in the above post, was definitely very slow on my computer. Noticeable lag at the console. I would recommend just checking to see if your product is greater than your current max, if it is, store that instead of pushing everything to an array. Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. Much appreciated.

```
//should find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3 digit numbers
var largestPalindrome = function() {

    var max = 0,
        product = 0;
    for (var num1 = 999; num1 >= 100; num1--) {
        for (var num2 = 999; num2 >= 100; num2--) {
            product = num1 * num2;
            product > max && isPalindrome(product.toString()) ?  max = product : 0;
        }
    }
    return max;
};

//check to see if product is a palindrome
var isPalindrome = function(product) {
    var palindromeCheck = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < product.length / 2; i++) {
        if (product[i] != product[product.length - i - 1])
            palindromeCheck = false;
    }
    return palindromeCheck;

   //return product === product.split("").reverse().join("");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can go for code given at this link
http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-problem-4/

As this save your CPU cycle from multiplication, which is quite costly operation.

Well even in this you can make some more to make to make it more like, you can modify its while loop a bit

```
while (!found) {
    firstHalf--;
    palin = makePalindrome(firstHalf);
    for (int i = 999; i > 99; i--) {
        if ((palin / i) > 999 || i*i < palin) {
            break;
        }

        if ((palin % i == 0)) {
            found = true;
            factors[0] = palin / i;
            factors[1] = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So here instead of moving from `i=999 : 100,` we can write it as `i=sqrt(palin):100`, as you can find factorial of number within its square root. Refer link [How to find Number is prime number or not!](http://planetmath.org/howtofindwhetheragivennumberisprimeornot)

And also you can change `if(condition)` to `if(!(palin%i))` as comparing with zero is usually not considered a good practice also comparing takes more CPU cycle compared to your simple negating bits.

Answer (score 1):

instead of creating an `Array` or `ArrayList` to store all palindromes, I just created another variable `max` and stored highest valued palindrome in it.

My code is in Java, but you can understand the logic from it.
Here is my code to better explain what I said (read comments):

```
package euler;
import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.Collections;

public class Problem4 {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int product=0;
            int max=0;
        for(int i=999;i>100;i--)
        {
            for (int j=i;j>100;j--)
            {
                product=i*j;

                if(isPalindrome(product))
                {
                    //Just store maximum value of product.
                    //Following if loop is required in your code,in place of return i*j;
                                    if(product>max)
                        { max=product; }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);    
    }
    //might be inefficient to create StringBuilder and again String to compare.
    public static boolean isPalindrome(int product)
    {
        boolean isPalindrome=false;
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(product)).reverse();
        if(temp.toString().equals(Integer.toString(product)))
        {
            isPalindrome=true;
        }
        return isPalindrome;
    }
}
```

What you are doing is returning and breaking out of the loop as soon as you get the first palindrome. Which in your case is not the maximum value palindrome.

Instead use an if condition and keep a track of maximum values and let the loop continue till end.

I have added the if condition that lets the loop running and registers the value.

Got the correct answer from this code.

PS. Thanks Xan for your input. I guess I could've explained it better first time.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question OP had. You're doing a re-implementation (in another language!) and the question was "what's wrong with [code]".

Comment: I see you honestly trying to explain the problem, but instead of presenting an alternative code with "see, this is solving it" you should edit the answer to explain the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a lot of posts for this question, this is the solution that i have come up with:

- Smallest number that is multiple of two 3 digits number is 10000(100*100)
- Largest number  that is multiple of two 3 digits number is 998001(999*999)

Our palindrome lies between these two number, write a program to loop  through these number and whenever you get a palindrome check whether its perfectly divisible by a 3 digit number and quotient is also a 3 digit number.

Below is my program in C#, the last number that it prints is our required answer, enjoy.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections;

namespace E
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            for(int i=10000;i<=998001;i++)
            {
                string s1 = i.ToString();
                char[] array = s1.ToCharArray();
                Array.Reverse(array);
                string s2 = new String(array);
                if(s1==s2)
                {

                    for(int j=100;j<=999;j++)
                    {
                        if(i%j==0 && i/j <= 999)
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine(i);        
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("done");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should be optimal

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
bool IsPalindrome(const T num) {
    T reverse = 0;
    T n = num;
    while (n > 0) {
        reverse = (reverse * 10) + n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return reverse == num;
}


template <typename T = long long int>
T LongestPalindromeFromProductOfNDigitNums(int n) {
    T result = 0, val = 0, max_n_digit_num = std::pow(10, n)-1,
    least_n_digit_num = std::pow(10, n-1);
    int n_checks = 0;
    for (T i = max_n_digit_num; i >= least_n_digit_num; --i) {
        if ((i*i) < result) {//found the highest palindrome
            break;
        }
        for (T j = i; j >= least_n_digit_num; --j) {
            val = i*j;
            ++n_checks;
            if (val < result) // any product i*j for the value of 'j' after this will be less than result
                break;
            if (IsPalindrome(val)) {
                if (val > result)
                    result = val;
                break;  // whenever a palindrome is found break since we only need highest one
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << " Total num of checks = " << n_checks << std::endl;
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int n = 3;
    std::cout << " LongestPalindromeFromProductOfNDigitNums for n = "
    << n << " is " << LongestPalindromeFromProductOfNDigitNums(n) << std::endl;
    n = 4;
    std::cout << " LongestPalindromeFromProductOfNDigitNums for n = "
    << n << " is " << LongestPalindromeFromProductOfNDigitNums(n) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/WoNSJP

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3:

```
// my approach is to make 6-digit palindrome first and then 
// check if I can divide it by 3-digit number 
// (you can see some visual listing at the end of the code)
// execution time on my laptop is around: 2.75409698486328 sec

import Foundation

func maxPalindrom() -> Int {

    var result = 999999
    var i = 9
    var j = 9
    var k = 9

    while true {
        while true {
            while true {
                print("in K loop: \(result) k = \(k)")

                if isDivisible(number: result) {
                    return result
                }
                if k <= 0 {
                    k = 9
                    result += 9900
                    break
                }
                result -= 1100
                k -= 1
            }

            print("in J loop: \(result)")
            if isDivisible(number: result) {
                return result
            }
            if j < 0 {
                j = 9
                result += 90090
                break
            }
            result -= 10010
            j -= 1
        }

        print("in I loop: \(result)")
        if isDivisible(number: result) {
            return result
        }
        if i < 0 {
            break
        }
        result -= 100001
        i -= 1
    }

    if result == 100001 {
        return -1
    }

    return -1
}


func isDivisible(number: Int) -> Bool {
    var i = 999

    while true {

        if number % i == 0 && number / i < 999 {
            return true
        }

        if i < 500 {
            return false
        }

        i -= 1
    }

}


let start = NSDate()
print(maxPalindrom())       // 906609
let end = NSDate()

print("executio time: \(end.timeIntervalSince(start as Date)) sec") // ~ execution time: 2.75409698486328 sec

//in K loop: 999999 k = 9
//in K loop: 998899 k = 8
//in K loop: 997799 k = 7
//in K loop: 996699 k = 6
//in K loop: 995599 k = 5
//in K loop: 994499 k = 4
//in K loop: 993399 k = 3
//in K loop: 992299 k = 2
//in K loop: 991199 k = 1
//in K loop: 990099 k = 0
//in J loop: 999999
//in K loop: 989989 k = 9
//in K loop: 988889 k = 8
//in K loop: 987789 k = 7
//in K loop: 986689 k = 6
//in K loop: 985589 k = 5
//in K loop: 984489 k = 4
//in K loop: 983389 k = 3
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers here are correct. If you want to save going through 900*900 loops, you can just loop through all palindromes between 10000 and 998001 and find if they are divisible by 3 digit number.

```
 static void largestpalindromeproduct(){
   int a=999,b=999,c=a*b,loopcounter=0;
   while(c>10000){
       loopcounter++;
       c--;
       if(isPalindrome(c))
           if(isDivisible(c))
           break;
   }

   System.out.println(" largest : " + c+ "\nloops:"+ loopcounter);       
}
static boolean isDivisible(int n){
    int a=999;
    while(a>=100){
        if(n%a==0){
            if(secondDividerIs3Digit(n,a))
            return true;
        }
        a--;
    }
    return false;
}
static boolean secondDividerIs3Digit(int n, int a){
    Integer b=n/a;
    if(b.toString().length()==3)
        return true;
    return false;
}

static boolean isPalindrome(int n){
    Integer i=new Integer(n);
    String p=i.toString();
    StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer(i.toString());
    s.reverse();
    if(p.equals(s.toString()))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a very simple solution, this one works

```
public class LargestPallendrome {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 999;
    int b = 999;

    long max = 0;

    while (a > 100) {
        long num = a * b;
        if (checkPallendrome(num)) {
            if (num > max)
                max = num;
        }
        if (b >= 100)
            b--;
        else {
            a--;
            b = 999;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
}

public static boolean checkPallendrome(long num) {
    String a = num + "";
    String b = new StringBuffer(num + "").reverse().toString();
    if (a.equals(b))
        return true;
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:javascript], not C#.

Answer (score 0):

Another Simple Solution in JavaScript

```
function reverseNumber(n)
{
    n = n + "";
    return n.split("").reverse().join("");
}

function palindrom(){
 var r= 1 , y =1;
var largest = 0;
 while(r <= 1000){ 
   var num1 =  r;
   var num2 = 0;
 while(num1 <= 1000 && num2 <= num1){ 
        product = num1 * num2;
   if (product == reverseNumber(product)){
     console.log(`${num1} x ${num2} = ${product}`);
          if(product > largest){
            largest = product;
          }
   }
   num1 = num1 + 1;
   num2= num2 + 1;
}
r++;
}
console.log(``)
console.log(`The largest is ${largest}`);
}
console.log(palindrom());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int tempAns = 0;
    int max = 999;
    for (int i = 100; i <= max; i++) {
        for (int j = max; j >= i; j--) {
            if (findPalindrome(i * j) && (i * j) > tempAns) {
                System.out.println("Palindrome: " + j + " * " + i + " = " + j * i);
                tempAns = i * j;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static boolean findPalindrome(int n) {
    String nString = String.valueOf(n);
    int j = 0;
    int stringLength = nString.length() - 1;
    for (int i = stringLength; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (nString.charAt(j) == nString.charAt(i)) {

            if (i == 0) {
                return true;
            }
            j++;

        } else if (nString.charAt(j) != nString.charAt(i)) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better because its using O(N) time complexity to find all the palindrome (As calculating palindrome of a six digit no is constant) and O(N<sup>2</sup>) nearly to find the actual palindrome that too worst case the moment its finding its first no we don't have to do any more calculation and here we are actually using the worst case on possible palindromic no. So I think its better

```
package ProjectEuler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Largest_Palindrome_Product {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count=0;
        for(int i=10000;i<998002;i++) {
            int x=i,c=0;
            while(x!=0) {
                c=c*10+x%10;
                x/=10;
            }
            if(c==i) {
            count++;
        }
        }
        int a[]=new int[count],count1=0;

    for(int i=10000;i<998002;i++) {
        int x=i,c=0;
        while(x!=0) {
            c=c*10+x%10;
            x/=10;
        }
        if(c==i) {
            a[count1]=i;
            count1++;
    }
    }
    Arrays.sort(a);
    tp:for(int i=count-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        for(int j=999;j>100;j--)
            if(a[i]%j==0&&a[i]/j<=999) {
        System.out.println(a[i]+" "+j+" "+a[i]/j);
        break tp;
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer is good. You also have not answered the question "Please explain what is wrong with my code".

Comment: This is better because its using O(N) time complexity to find all the palindrome(
As calculating palindrome of a six digit no is constant) and O(N^2) nearly to find the actual palindrome that too worst case the moment its finding its first no we don't have to do any more calculation and here we are actually using the worst case on possible palindromic no.
So I think its better.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in Javascript. Simple & easy!

```
let num1 = 999;
let num2 = 999;
let arr = [];

function check(x, y)
{
    if(String(x*y) == String(x*y).split("").reverse().join(""))
    {
        return true;
    }
return false;
}

for(let i=0; i<999999; i++)
{
    if(check(num1, num2))
    {
        arr.push(num1*num2);
        num1--;
        num2 = num1+1;
    }
num2--;
}

console.log(arr.sort((x, y) => y-x)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I check it some times with `random.randint`.  In python 3.7.1, you should run it with CMD and after 20 sec you will get the right answer.

```
import random
x,y,z,a,b=100,100,' ','',0
while 100<=x<=999 and 100<=y<=999:
    a=x*y
    x=random.randint(900,999)
    y=random.randint(900,999)
    print(x,' x ',y,'=')
    z=len(str(a))
    if z==6:
        if str(a)[0] == str(a)[5]:
            if str(a)[1] == str(a)[4]:
                if str(a)[2] == str(a)[3]:
                    print(a,'yes')
                    exit(a)
    else:
        pass
#906609
```

Answer (score 0):

Readable option:

```
function maxPalindrome(num) {
  let maxPalindrome = 1;

  for (let i = num; i > 0; i--) {
    for (let j = num; j > 0; j--) {
      const product = i * j;

      if (
        product.toString() === product.toString().split("").reverse().join("")
        && product > maxPalindrome
      ) {
        maxPalindrome = product;
      }
    }
  }

  return maxPalindrome;
}

console.log(maxPalindrome(999));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done with C#:

```
public static void maxPali() {
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 99; i >= 10; i--) {
        for (int j = 99; j >= 10; j--) {
            if (i*j == reverse(i*j))
                max = max >= (i*j) ? max : (i*j);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(max);
}

public static int reverse(int num) {
    int rev = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        int rem = num % 10;
        rev = (rev * 10) + rem;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return rev;
}
```

JavaScript solution:

```
(function main() {
    let start = 100,
        stop = 999,
        step = 1;

    let arr = Array(Math.ceil((stop + step - start) / 
    step)).fill(start).map((x, y) => x + y * step);
    let max = 0;
    arr.slice(0).reverse().map(function(i) { 
    arr.slice(0).reverse().map(function(j) {
        if (i*j == (i*j).toString().split('').reverse().join(''))
            if (max < (i*j))
                max = i*j;
    });
});
console.log(max);  }());
```

Answer (score 0):

One more optimization is we can break the inner loop if the current product is less than current largest palindrome:

```
var isPalindrome = function(number) {
  return number.toString() === number.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
};

var largestPalindrome = 0;
for (var i = 999; i > 100; i--) {
  for (var j = i; j > 100; j--) {
    if (i * j < largestPalindrome) {
      break;
    }
    if (isPalindrome(i * j)) {
      largestPalindrome = i * j;
    }
  }
}
console.log(largestPalindrome);
```