# I am trying to solve a question about palindrome of number

Tags: python, function, loops

I want to get the largest palindrome made from two 3digits number.. I need some advice here.

```
Y=?
for I in range(100,1000):
    if i*i==y:
        print(y)
```

I want y to be a form of number where I use comparison for its index like `number[0]==number[-1] and  number[1]==number[-2]`

I think function can really help but am still new to it. Thanks

Comment: Dunsin, try to be more explanatory, some of the concepts here aren't clear to everyone. Perhaps you can explain in other words what you mean when talking about using comparison for its index in y. Also always keep variables in the same casing :)

Comment: To get palindrome .. Example of a palindrome is 1234321 so I made those index equal to one another

Comment: Dunsin, if your getting error while executing the code, please check for the correct indentation while copying

Answer (score 0):

A simple palindrome checker is just check if a string is the same backwards as it is forwards:

```
def is_palindrome(integer):

    return str(integer) == str(integer)[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the accepted answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286890/find-the-largest-palindrome-made-from-the-product-of-two-3-digit-numbers-javas). It is exactly the same problem as yours.
Here is the python version of the answer using the function proposed by HoboProber.

```
def largestPalindrome():
  palindromes = []    
  for i in range(999,100,-1):
    for j in range(999,100,-1):
      mul = j*i
      if(is_palindrome(mul)):
        palindromes.append(mul)
  return max(palindromes)

def is_palindrome(integer):
    return str(integer) == str(integer)[::-1]

print(largestPalindrome())
```