# Euler project problem with the error message

Tags: python

Euler project problem 4: 
A palindromic number reads the same both ways.
The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

below are my codes and got the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 10, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

can you advise?

```
def palindromic(a, b, c):
    result = a * 10 ** 5 + b * 10 ** 4 + c * 10 ** 3 + c * 10 ** 2 + b * 10 + a * 1
    return result

list = []

for a in range(9):
    for b in range(9):
        for c in range(9):
            list = list.extend(palindromic(a, b, c))

largest =  max(list)
```

Comment: Always post **the whole error message** with **full traceback** please. (1) You are confusing `append` with `extend` (2) Both `.append` and `.extend` modify the list in place; they don't return a value, and (3) Don't use built-ins (such as `list`) as variable names.

Comment: Shouldn't your for loops use range(10) rather than range(9) (i.e. to use numbers from 0 to 9)?

Comment: Even after correcting the coding errors (see @alexanderBrockmeier answer), this code produces an incorrect result of 999999 since it uses an incorrect algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Seluk is right on his opinions, you may also set range to 10 as it is the upper bound (so 0-9 is range(10) ...)

```
In [67]:
...:
...:
...: _list = []
...:
...: for a in range(10):
...:     for b in range(10):
...:         for c in range(10):
...:             _list.append(palindromic(a, b, c))
...:
...: largest =  max(_list)
...: print(largest)
...:
...:
```

999999

And keep asking questions, some answers may sound picky, but the just aim to more precission and effectivity ;-)
have fun!

Comment: Doesn't this product a result of 999999 not 888888?

Comment: yep, let's call it a typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

@AlexanderBrockmeier answer corrects the errors in OP code.

However, the problem is the OP algorithm is incorrect, so correcting the code produces incorrect answers.

A valid algorithm is obtained by translating [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286890/find-the-largest-palindrome-made-from-the-product-of-two-3-digit-numbers-javas) from JavaScript to Python.

```
def is_palin(i):
  """ Return True if a number is a Palindrome, False otherwise """
  s = str(i)
  return s == s[::-1]

def largestPalindrome():
    """ Finds largest Palindrome made by multiplying 2 three digit numbers """
    # algorithm basically tries all pairs of 3 digit numbers (i.e. 101 to 999)
    arr = []
    for i in range(999, 100, -1):
      for j in range(999, 100, -1):
        mul = j * i
        if is_palin(mul):
          arr.append((mul, j, i)) 

    return max(arr, key = lambda x: x[0])  # max based upon product


result = largestPalindrome()
print(f'Largest number is {result[0]}, with factors of {result[1]} x {result[2]}')
```

**Output**

```
Largest number is 906609, with factors of 913 x 993
```

**Problem with Originally Posted (OP) Algorithm**

From @AlexanderBrockmeier answer we see the OP code produces an answer of 999,999

But, this does not have two 3 digit factors, since its factors are:

```
1 × 999999 = 999,999
3 × 333333 = 999,999
7 × 142857 = 999,999
9 × 111111 = 999,999
11 × 90909 = 999,999
13 × 76923 = 999,999
21 × 47619 = 999,999
27 × 37037 = 999,999
33 × 30303 = 999,999
37 × 27027 = 999,999
39 × 25641 = 999,999
63 × 15873 = 999,999
77 × 12987 = 999,999
91 × 10989 = 999,999
99 × 10101 = 999,999
111 × 9009 = 999,999
117 × 8547 = 999,999
143 × 6993 = 999,999
189 × 5291 = 999,999
231 × 4329 = 999,999
259 × 3861 = 999,999
273 × 3663 = 999,999
297 × 3367 = 999,999
333 × 3003 = 999,999
351 × 2849 = 999,999
407 × 2457 = 999,999
429 × 2331 = 999,999
481 × 2079 = 999,999
693 × 1443 = 999,999
777 × 1287 = 999,999
819 × 1221 = 999,999
999 × 1001 = 999,999
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the revised code.

```
def palindromic(a, b, c):
    result = a * 10 ** 5 + b * 10 ** 4 + c * 10 ** 3 + c * 10 ** 2 + b * 10 + a * 1
    return result

_list = []

for a in range(10):
    for b in range(10):
        for c in range(10):
            _list.append(palindromic(a, b, c))

print(max(_list))

import time
start_time = time.time()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```